# Can lambda expressions be optimized by the compiler?

Tags: c#, optimization, lambda

Can the compiler/runtime reorder or inline expression trees?

If I got the following code:

```
public static int SomeSimpleMethod(int x) {
    return x;
}

void Main() {
    Expression<Func<bool>> expr = () => SomeSimpleMethod(2) == 3;
}
```

Can `expr` then include something else than (in pseudo code)

```
Expression.Lambda
    Expression.Equals
         Expression.Call
             Expression.Constant
         Expression.Constant
```

**Edit**

I am just parsing the expression tree to find some items like the name of the method call ("SomeSimpleMethod"). The lambda will never be executed so I just want to ensure that the method call is not optimized away from the expression tree.

Comment: Optimize how? Size? Speed? Number of chickens slaughtered?

Comment: @RitchMelton: While that's a valid thing to point out in general, it's pretty universal that an unqualified "optimize" means "for speed".

Comment: @Ritch Melton: [number of toenails cut](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7769032/what-is-the-optimal-jewish-toenail-cutting-algorithm)

Comment: @delnan - I disagree with your assertion. When asked on SO, it quite often means, 'how do I do this with less code (typed by me)'

Comment: I doubt even the most misguided speed-seekers on the one hand, nor the most less-premature-than-thou Knuth quoters-out-of-context on the other, would disagree that if a compiler produced code that was smaller in run-time memory but without any effect on speed, that it would still count as an optimisation.
That said, I think the question is a fair one for *any* optimisation. The OP wants to know what the compiler does when it gets the input they describe, a good answer tells them just that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler will never optimize that.

Comment: What about the expression compiler?

Comment: @Oded: That's a completely separate question.  However, I rather doubt that it looks into other methods.  The JITter might, though.  Also, you mean _compiler_; there is no expression _evaluator_.

Comment: Just what I wanted. Thanks. Do you know if it is specified in the standard?

Answer (score 0):

The compiler can't optimize it because it doesn't know how it will be executed. It is often (usually?) the case that expressions actually get executed not by the CLR but by something else like a SQL engine. Since the semantics of other execution engines may not exactly match those of C#, it is important that expressions are translated exactly as written into data.