# how many different sequences that the difference between every adjacent pair of numbers is larger than 1

Tags: algorithm

I just find a problem like this

"Give you N different integers, do you know how many different sequences that the difference between every adjacent pair of numbers is larger than 1?"

And when the integers are "1 2 3", then the answer is zero, when the integers are "5 3 1", then the answer is 6, for "1 3 5" "1 5 3" "3 1 5" "3 5 1" "5 1 3" "5 3 1" satisfy the problem, I just tried all I could do but I couldn't solve it, so my question is, how to write a algorithm to solve it.

Thankyou.

Here is my program

```
int n;bool vi[30];int a[30];int b[30];int counter = 0;
void dfs(int k)
{
    if ( k == n)
    {
        for (int i = 2; i <= n; i ++)
            if (fabs(b[i] - b[i - 1]) <= 1) return ;
        counter ++;
        return ;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i ++)
    {
    if (!vi[i])
    {
        b[k + 1] = a[i];
        vi[i] = true;
        dfs(k + 1);
        vi[i] = false;
        }
    }
}
int main (void)
{
        cin >> n;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i ++)
            cin >> a[i];
        memset(vi, 0, sizeof(vi));
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i ++)
        {
            vi[i] = true;b[1] = a[i];dfs(1);vi[i] = false;
        }
        cout << counter << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is O(n!) fast enough for you?

Comment: How large does N get? You can refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7769032/what-is-the-optimal-jewish-toenail-cutting-algorithm/7769328#7769328) question for a O(N!) solution.

Comment: @penartur  I just got one second, and n is less than or equal to 25.

Comment: @Kevin   I just got one second, and n is less than or equal to 25.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark  OK, I used a deep search to solve it, but my friend said if I just got one second to solve, then my program will not work out.

Comment: @Laurent: and still you haven't posted any code.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark  I have posted it.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I know this is a Q&A site for programming, don't you think this problem is a programming problem? It may be a math problem, but I want to use program to find the answer.Thankyou for your help.

Comment: Is this a new Codility challenge or something? I'd be interested to know where it came from and if it has any applications.

Comment: @SteveHaigh  no applications, I had a talk with my friends, and he came out this problem, we are majoring software engineering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the question, "How many different sequences are there..." can be solved without enumerating every combination. Which is a good thing, because `25!` is approximately 1.55 x 10^24, or way more than *any* existing computer is going to enumerate in a second. Or in a year.

This is a math problem, specifically combinatorics. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorics and possibly http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinations for information on how you would go about solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that "meet-in-the-middle" principle could give reasonable work-time.

Sketch:

Divide number list into equal parts (+-1 for odd length). There are C(N, N div 2) variants.

Calculate number of valid permutations of the first half and second half for all fixed last and first elements (recursively). Multiply counts for compatible last and first elements.

Edit: **More  reliable variant found**:

Let's FullSet = (A, B, C, D)
To calculate valid permutations, starting with A, we should count valid permutations of  set (B, C, D) without A, starting with values, compatible with A. The same is true for valid permutations, starting with B and so on...

I've initially written recursive function to visit all initial values and count valid permutations for sets without these values. It is suitable for small sets only.

Then I've used memoization to remember counts for combination [InitialValue, Set] (to avoid repeating calculation for the same set). This is up-down dynamic programming.

And finally I've transformed dynamic programming from up-down to ascending style  - it is possible because we can fill the memoization table sequentially.

Complexity is O(N^2 * 2^N), and memory consumption is O(N * 2^N), because we should examine (almost) all 2^N subsets of the full set. So I could use this method for N <= 20 (if Int64 type is enough for Count).

Delphi code:

```
var
  A: TArray<Byte>;
  Memo: array of array of Int64;
  N, Mask, msk, index, i: Integer;
  Count: Int64;
  OnlyOneOneBit: Boolean;

begin
  A := TArray<Byte>.Create(1, 2, 4, 5);

  N := Length(A);
  Mask := (1 shl N) - 1;//binary 000111111 with n ones

  SetLength(Memo, 1 shl N {2^N}, N);

  for msk := 1 to Mask do begin // all possible subsets, excluding empty one
    OnlyOneOneBit := 0 = (msk and (msk - 1));
    for index := 0 to N - 1 do
       if OnlyOneOneBit then
         Memo[msk, index] := (msk shr index) and 1 // 1 if indexth bit = 1 else 0
       else if 0 <> ((msk shr index) and 1) then begin
         Count := 0;
         for i := 0 to N - 1 do
           if Abs(A[i] - A[index]) > 1 then //compatible numbers
              Count := Count + Memo[msk xor (1 shl index), i];
     //use previous result for the set without index element, starting with ith
         Memo[msk, index] := Count;
       end;
  end;

  Count := 0;
  for index := 0 to N - 1 do
    Count := Count + Memo[Mask, index];
```

Result for used example (1, 2, 4, 5) is 8
Hand-checking: 1425 1524 2415 2514 4152 4251 5142 5241

Answer (score 0):

In order to find a solution faster than the O(n!) approach of enumerating all permutations and checking them - I'll note that this problem is an instance of counting all [Hamiltonian paths](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HamiltonianPath.html) on the graph (V, E) where V are the members of the original list and E are edges connecting members that can be adjacent.  (So that your second example would be V={1,3,5} and E={(1,3),(3,5),(1,5)}.)

I don't know how you'd go about counting Hamiltonian paths efficiently but perhaps that's the way to a solution.